# Laravel Model create function returns column with null value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

In Laravel, When I run the following query, it returns a row with null values.

```
//Cards.php

public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    $this->gateway = StripeGateway;
} 


protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'card_id', 'customer_id', 'exp_year', 'exp_month', 'funding', 'brand', 'last4'];

public function createNewCardFromCustomer($user_id, $customer)
    {

        $result = $this->create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'card_id' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->id,
            'exp_year' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->exp_year,
            'exp_month' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->exp_month,
            'funding' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->funding,
            'brand' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->brand,
            'last4' => $customer['sources']['data'][0]->last4
        ]);

        return $result;

    }
```

Even the Model static create method receives the right parameters. And I've taken care of the mass assignment also.

Comment: So `createNewCardFromCustomer` is a method inside the cards model? And how exactly are you calling this method? Just making sure I understood your situation before trying to give you a response.

Comment: yes, it's a function within the `Cards` Model. I'm calling it like `$card =  (new  Cards())->createNewCardFromCustomer($user->id, $customer);`

Comment: do `dd($customer)` check you are definitely passing something in and your references are right

Comment: I've checked and I'm getting all values. Also, in my constructor for this model, I've $this->gateway = StripeGateway;  will this affect anything?

Comment: Can you show your constructor?

Comment: @patricus: added the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on Laracasts too :)

Anyway, you have to change your constructor to this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    $this->gateway = StripeGateway;
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

You are overriding the Model's base constructor, which changes its default behavior. Laravel uses the constructor for a lot of things (create method, relationships, etc.).

The base model's constructor function does several things, but one very important part of it is that it accepts an array to fill out its attributes as can be seen here:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

So, after you set your gateway property, you should call the parent's constructor function and pass the attributes.

Comment: Yeah :) Just wanted someone to post the answer here as well :) Thanks mate.